# Contravariant functor from exponential in a topos

Tags: category-theory

In an elementary topos $\sf E$, with subobject classifier $\Omega$, how do I prove that $\Omega^-$ extends on arrows to define a contravariant functor?

I noticed that, given $f:a\to b$, one can define $\mathrm{ev}_b\circ (1_{\Omega^b}\times f):\Omega^b\times a\to \Omega$, to get $\Omega^b\to \Omega^a$. However I don't understand how to use the fact that $\Omega$ is a subobject classifier, to obtain the the functoriality; would you give me a hint? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the fact that $\Omega$ is a subobject classifier: you get a contravariant functor in that argument using any internal hom. All you need is the adjunction, which gives you that the morphism $f:B \rightarrow \Omega^A$ corresponds to $B \times A \xrightarrow{f \times 1} \Omega^A \times A \xrightarrow{ev_A} \Omega$.

---

The proof goes as follows: $\Omega^{(g \circ f)}$ should be the morphism $\Omega^C \rightarrow \Omega^A$ that corresponds with

$$ \Omega^C \times A \xrightarrow{1 \times f} \Omega^C \times B \xrightarrow{1 \times g} \Omega^C \times C \xrightarrow{ev_C} \Omega $$

as you reasoned. In other words, it is the morphism $\Omega^C \rightarrow \Omega^A$ such that

$$ (\Omega^C \times A \xrightarrow{\Omega^{(g \circ f)} \times 1} \Omega^A \times A \xrightarrow{ev_A} \Omega) = (\Omega^C \times A \xrightarrow{1 \times f} \Omega^C \times B \xrightarrow{1 \times g} \Omega^C \times C \xrightarrow{ev_C} \Omega)$$

---

The composite $\Omega^f \circ \Omega^g$ also corresponds to a morphism $\Omega^C \times A \rightarrow \Omega$. To work out which morphism that is, calculate

$$ \Omega^C \times A \xrightarrow{\Omega^g \times 1} \Omega^B \times A \xrightarrow{\Omega^f \times 1} \Omega^A \times A \xrightarrow{ev_A} \Omega  $$

using a diagram chase and the fact that $\Omega^f$ and $\Omega^g$ also correspond to particular morphisms under the adjunction as you defined them. When you show that

$$(\Omega^C \times A \xrightarrow{\Omega^g \times 1} \Omega^B \times A \xrightarrow{\Omega^f \times 1} \Omega^A \times A \xrightarrow{ev_A} \Omega) = (\Omega^C \times A \xrightarrow{1 \times f} \Omega^C \times B \xrightarrow{1 \times g} \Omega^C \times C \xrightarrow{ev_C} \Omega)$$

you will have proven that $\Omega^{(g \circ f)} = \Omega^f \circ \Omega^g$.

---

(You'll also need to show that the identity is preserved, but that uses a similar technique and is easier.)